# Flash Yahoo Maps has stopped working?

Tags: flash, yahoo-maps

In the past week it appears that Yahoo has changed their crossdomain file to only accept Yahoo domains (http://maps.yahooapis.com/crossdomain.xml):

This is causing my applications that use Yahoo Maps to stop working (i.e. security exception).  I cannot proxy the calls to Yahoo because the URL is embedded in the MXP file that Yahoo distributes.  Does anyone know if there's a workaround or update to this?

Answer (score 0):

Interestingly Yahoo's own examples on the following page aren't working right now either:
http://developer.yahoo.com/maps/flash/asGettingStarted.html